# OpenCV::glob() does not get image names with order

Tags: c++, opencv, readfile, glob

In a folder I have `190` images named as `0.jpg`, `1.jpg`, ...

The code:

```
vector<String> filenames;
glob(inputFolderPath, filenames);

for (size_t i = 0; i < filenames.size(); i++)
{
    img = imread(filenames[i]);
}
```

It reads images have name 0, 1, 10, 100, 101, 102, 103...

Why can't I read images with order of its names 0, 1, 2, 3, ...?

Comment: Because that's the alphanumeric/lexical order... to do what you want you need 0 padding: 000, 001, ... 010, ... 100

Comment: @Miki Yes, it worked with 0 padding